# How to get the exact online status of the users for one to one chat in quick blox android?

Tags: android, quickblox

I need to find the online status of the chat users in one to one chat
but it is always showing more than 5 minutes.

```
/** The current time. */
long currentTime;

/** The user's last requested  time. */
long userLastRequestAtTime;

currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
userLastRequestAtTime = qbUsers.getLastRequestAt().getTime();
// if user didn't do anything last 5 minutes (5*60*1000 milliseconds)    
if((currentTime - userLastRequestAtTime) > 5*60*1000) {
     LogMessage.v("status","offline");
else
     LogMessage.v("status","online");
```

Comment: what does *quick blox* mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your adding a condition which is delaying your status update

you need to remove this line

```
if((currentTime - userLastRequestAtTime) > 5*60*1000)
```

Comment: You should add some explaination to avoid low quality post.